# Error Run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error

Tags: vba, excel

I have the below code to update pivot table filters from cells, the update to 3 out of the 4 filters works fine, but 1 does not work.

line **`'pf2.CurrentPage = pf2_New'`** gives the **`'Error Run-time error '1004': application-defined or object-defined error'`** error. If the line is commented out the code works fine.

Code is:

```
Sub cmdUpdate()
'
' cmdUpdate Macro
'

    Dim pt1 As PivotTable

    Dim pf1 As PivotField
    Dim pf1_New As String

    Dim pf2 As PivotField
    Dim pf2_New As String

    Dim pf3 As PivotField
    Dim pf3_New As String

    Dim pf4 As PivotField
    Dim pf4_New As String


    Set pt1 = Worksheets("HIDE").PivotTables("table_name")

    Set pf1 = pt1.PivotFields("pivot_field_1")
    pf1_New = Worksheets("HIDE").Range("L11").Value

    Set pf2 = pt1.PivotFields("pivot_field_2")
    pf2_New = Worksheets("HIDE").Range("L12").Value

    Set pf3 = pt1.PivotFields("pivot_field_3")
    pf3_New = Worksheets("HIDE").Range("L13").Value

    Set pf4 = pt1.PivotFields("pivot_field_4")
    pf4_New = Worksheets("HIDE").Range("L14").Value


    With pt1

        Sheets("HIDE").Visible = True
        Sheets("HIDE").Select

        pf1.CurrentPage = pf1_New
        pf2.CurrentPage = pf2_New
        pf4.CurrentPage = pf3_New
        pf4.CurrentPage = pf4_New

        Sheets("HIDE").Visible = False
        Sheets("Summary").Select
        Range("A1").Select

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Investigate Worksheets("HIDE").Range("L12"), you should only get that error if that cell is undefined, or does not have a valid value for ".CurrentPage".

Comment: `.CurrentPage` is not a string.  Maybe you meant `.CurrentPage.Name` ?

Comment: Thanks for the Sugestion, @Pkatona, the varaible **`'pf2_New'`** is successfully set.

Comment: @chris neilsen,  **`'CurrentPage.Name'`** gives the same error.

Comment: What exactly is in L12?

Comment: Cell L12 is a vlookup returning a text string.

Comment: I'm still experiencing this problem,  does anyone have any other suggestions?

Comment: Do a debug.print of the L12 value (or pf2_new). I think the value there is the problem.

Comment: @PKatona I tried debug.print and this shows the correct value in L12 and pf2_new. I also hard code the value in L12 and continue to get the error then changed the input to pf3_new and get the error which suggestions **`pf2.CurrentPage `** is causing the problem

Comment: Then what is the value? That is what several of us have been trying to determine. It might be the "correct" value for what you want, but it could be incompatible with where you're assigning it. I might also try putting some other character around the debug.print, like parens, to see if the value has embedded special characters. Or take a Len of the value. There is something in there that is causing the problem.

Comment: As I said I changed the input to a hard coded value, the value being "test" and got the same error. The other filters successfully have numbers and characters, this one will be a text string < 100 characters. If I select the same item from the pivot filter manually the selection works. I have also tried a number of different selections and all give the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, and I had resolved it

because I want to filter a **Date** type PivotFields. I wrong to set a String value to it. When I chage the CurrentPage value to Date type value, the error is fixed

Notes: if select All PivotFields, you can set a String value "All" to CurrentPage ,but the other value must be the same as itself's PivotFields type.